# Replace a line in Crontab with another using Sed

Tags: shell, sed

I want to replace this line below

```
0 */4 * * *  sleep `expr ${RANDOM:0:4} / 2` ; /sbin/service osad stop ;/bin/rm -f /etc/sysconfig/rhn/osad-auth.conf ; /sbin/service osad start ; /usr/sbin/rhn_check ; /usr/sbin/rhn-profile-sync
```

with the one below in crontab, a file even /var/spool/cron/root

```
1,11,21,31,41,51 * * * * /sbin/rhn_check
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's|0 \*/4 \* \* \*  sleep `expr ${RANDOM:0:4} / 2` ; /sbin/service osad stop ;/bin/rm -f /etc/sysconfig/rhn/osad-auth.conf ; /sbin/service osad start ; /usr/sbin/rhn_check ; /usr/sbin/rhn-profile-sync|1,11,21,31,41,51 * * * * /sbin/rhn_check|' /var/spool/cron/root
```

Output:

```
1,11,21,31,41,51 * * * * /sbin/rhn_check
```

If you want to edit "in place" add option `-i`.

Comment: Thank you. How can I just delete the first line only using wild characters? The line is ending in rhn-profile-sync. I want to delete every before rhn-profile-sync until the beginning of the line.

Comment: To delete only first line ending in "rhn-profile-sync": `sed '/rhn-profile-sync$/{d;q}' file`